# How to use callback in my code? --- Android app development

Tags: android, eclipse, callback, countdowntimer

I am currently working on an android app that has multiple CountDownTimer. During a certain period of time of the day, only one of those CountDownTimer would be activated(e.g. during 9am to 10am, object myCountDownTimer[0] would be activated and count down from 9am until 10am, but during 10am to 11am, myCountDownTimer[0] would be deactivated and myCountDownTimer[1] would be working and count down until 11am). But now I have come across a problem. In order to activate myCountDownTimer[1] after myCountDownTimer[0] finish counting down, I have to call the constructor of myCountDownTimer[1] outside the MyCountDownTimer class. I tried to initialize the object myCountDownTimer[1] in the onFinish() method inside the MyCountDownTimer class but my app keeps crashing. After doing some research, I figured that I have to use a callback to communicate between different classes. I tried to understand the callback method by reading and watching tutorials online, but I failed. I am still confused. Could you please take a look at my code and tell me how to implement callback in my code? Thank you so much and have a good day.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
//...

private final int TIMER_SUM = 10;
MyCountDownTimer [] myCountDownTimer;
private int timerIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer[TIMER_SUM];
    timerIndex = 0;
    myCountDownTimer[timerIndex] = new MyCountDownTimer(getRemainingTime(), 100);
    myCountDownTimer[timerIndex].start();
}

private long getRemainingTime()
{
    //The method that returns the remaining milliseconds until next specified time.
}

private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{   
    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture,
            long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

        timerIndex++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        //This method display the remaining time.

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        this.cancel();

        //I want to add a callback here to tell the MainActivity to create a new MyCountDownTimer object.
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you make another class for MyCountDownTimer?

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: If you want to call method within MainActivity then you can use only normal method. Even as I see you just need to put     myCountDownTimer[timerIndex] = new MyCountDownTimer(getRemainingTime(), 100);
    myCountDownTimer[timerIndex].start(); in your onFinish method.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. I made a mistake actually... But thank you so much, you really helped me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out by yourself, and what was that actual mistake?

Comment: I messed up the index variable in my actual code. I didn't post my real code so you cannot see my mistake. It is a careless mistake. I guess next time I will post my actual code so that everyone can see.